# Understanding lexical scoping of "use open ..." of Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, io

```
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
```

Above statement seems to be effective in its lexical scope only and should not affect outside of it's scope. But I have observed the following.

```
$ cat data
€
```

#1

```
$ perl -e '
    open (my $fh, "<encoding(UTF-8)", "data");  
    print($_) while <$fh>;'
Wide character in print at -e line 1, <$fh> line 1.
€
```

The `Wide character ...` warning is perfect here. But

#2

```
$ perl
  my ($fh, $row);
  {
      use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
      open ($fh, "<", "data");
  }
  $row = <$fh>;
  chomp($row);
  printf("%s (0x%X)", $row, ord($row));

  € (0x20AC)
```

Does not show the wide character warning!! Here is whats going on here imo

- We are using open pragma to set the IO streams to UTF-8, including STDOUT.
- Opening the file inside the same scope. It reads the character as multibyte char.
- But printing outside the scope. The print statement should show "Wide character" warning, but it is not. Why?

Now look at the following, a little variation

#3

```
my ($fh, $row);
{
    use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
}
open ($fh, "<", "data");
$row = <$fh>;
chomp($row);
printf("%s (0x%X)", $row, ord($row));

â¬ (0xE2)
```

Now this time since the open statement is out of the lexical scope, the `open` opened the file in non utf-8 mode.

Does this mean `use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );` statement changes the STDOUT globally but STDIN within lexical scope?

Comment: See also the talk [A Million Billion Squiggly Characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmTeXcEixEg) by Ricardo Signes at YAPC NA 2016. The discussion of the `open` pragma starts at [35:44](https://youtu.be/TmTeXcEixEg?t=2144)

Comment: Yes the `open qw(:std)` changes the standard handles globally. As discussed by Ricardo in the above mentioned talk.

Comment: The `:std` part is not scoped lexically, only the changing of the default layers used by `open()` which you don't even use in your snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using `STDIN`. You're opening a file with an explicit encoding (except for your last example) and reading from that.

The `use open qw(:std ...)` affects the *standard* file handles, but you're only using standard output. When you don't use that and print UTF-8 data to standard output, you get the warning.

In your last example, you don't read the data with an explicit encoding, so when you print it to standard output, it's already corrupted.

That's the trick of encodings no matter what they are. Every part of the process has to be correct.

If you want `use open` to affect all file handles, you have to import it differently. There are several examples in the top of the documentation.

Comment: You are right. I was not using STDIN. But I am still not clear why I am not getting warning in #2. The `$row` should contain a single multibyte character. But STDOUT has no UTF-8 flag enabled. Hence the `print` should show the "wide character..." warning. Which point im missing here?

Comment: @Samiron maybe that the :std part of open isn't lexically scoped?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `open qw(:std)` pragma does not seem to behave as a lexical pragma since it changes the IO layers associated with the standard handles `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` globally. Even code earlier in source file is affected since the `use` statement happens at compile time. So the following

```
say join ":", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDIN);
{
   use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
}
```

prints ( on my linux platform ) :

```
unix:perlio:encoding(utf-8-strict):utf8
```

whereas without the `use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std )` it would just print
`unix:perlio`.

A way to not affect the global `STDOUT` for example is to duplicate the handle within a lexical scope and then add IO layers to the duplicate handle within that scope:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $str = "€";
say join ":", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDOUT);
{
    open ( my $out, '>&STDOUT' ) or die "Could not duplicate stdout: $!";
    binmode $out, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
    say $out $str;
}
say join ":", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDOUT);
say $str;
```

with output:

```
unix:perlio
€
unix:perlio
Wide character in say at ./p.pl line 16.
€
```